# Log4j2 only keeping 10 days of logs

Tags: log4j2

I'm ussing log4j2 and even though I have configured a 90 days log retention policy the application is only keeping 10 days of logs.

Here is my current working configuration that should work according to the documentation.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Configuration>
    <Properties>
    <Property name="log-path">/var/log/japay/</Property>
    </Properties>
    <Appenders>
    <RollingFile name="EventsLog" fileName="${log-path}/log.log"
    filePattern="${log-path}/log-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log" >
    <PatternLayout>
    <pattern>[%p] %d %c %M - %m%n</pattern>
    </PatternLayout>
    <Policies>
    <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1"/>
    <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="2048 MB" />
    </Policies>
    <DefaultRolloverStrategy>
         <Delete basePath="${log-path}" maxDepth="2">
        <IfFileName glob="*/log-*.log" />
        <IfLastModified age="P90D" />
     </Delete>
</DefaultRolloverStrategy>
</RollingFile>
<RollingFile name="TransactionLog" fileName="${log-path}/transacciones.log"
filePattern="${log-path}/transacciones-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log" >
<PatternLayout>
<pattern>[%p] %d %c %M - %m%n</pattern>
</PatternLayout>
<Policies>
<TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1"/>
<SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="2048 MB" />
</Policies>
<DefaultRolloverStrategy>
  <Delete basePath="${log-path}" maxDepth="2">
    <IfFileName glob="*/transacciones-*.log" />
    <IfLastModified age="P90D" />
  </Delete>
</DefaultRolloverStrategy>
</RollingFile>
</Appenders>
<Loggers>
<Logger name="com.mx.japay.transacciones" level="info" additivity="false">
<appender-ref ref="TransactionLog" level="info"/>
</Logger>
<Logger name="com.mx.japay" level="info" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="EventsLog"/>
</Logger>
</Loggers>
</Configuration>
```